# Facing Undefined default URL for page object issue while running serenium scripts

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am running my scripts with serenity framework. Earlier, it was working fine when I was running multiple feature files simultaneously with same or different default url's as per the need. However now I am facing below error message while execution of second feature file/second step definition class:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Undefined default URL for page object WelcomePageRepository$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$622ac9e3
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageUrls.verified(PageUrls.java:69)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageUrls.getStartingUrl(PageUrls.java:47)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.open(PageObject.java:730)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.open(PageObject.java:719)
    at org.gradle.stepdef.WelcomePageStepDefSerenity.user_is_on_Welcome_Page_with_successful_login(WelcomePageStepDefSerenity.java:47)
    at ?.Given User is on Welcome Page with successful login(SearchTextBoxFunctionality.feature:24)
```

I am not sure what exactly is root cause behind this, because it was working absolutely fine for me sometimes back. Below is my package and class structure.

```
|----src
| |----test
| | |----java
| | | |----org
| | | | |----gradle
| | | | | |----TestRunnerSerenity.java
| | | | | | |----stepdef
| | | | | | | |----Loginstepdef.java                                    
| | | | | | | |----WelcomePagestepdef.java                      
| | | | | | | | |----repository                                     
| | | | | | | | | |----LoginPageRepository.java
| | | | | | | | | |----WelcomeReposi.java
```

In the above structure I am providing `@defaulturl` in the classes under repository package.

At below location my feature files are stored.

```
|----src
| |----test
| | |----resoruces
| | | |----features
| | | | |----LoginFeature.feature
| | | | |----SearchTextbox.feature
```

Can you please guide me what exactly I need to do to resolve above mentioned error as I am not sure it is so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates or suggestions on this. Thanks

Comment: Any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the "serenity.properties"  file is missed in project root folder.if the file is not there in the directory the above error is thrown.